# how to use divider as a date in ionic v3

Tags: ionic3

**my data like this ( like history date )**

```
[
{firstName:'saurabh' , date:'20/03/2017'},

{firstName:'rahul' , date:'20/03/2017'},

{firstName:'mukesh' , date:'20/04/2017'},

{firstName:'harish' , date:'19/01/2017'}
]
```

Comment: What is the problem? Describe it with examples or screenshots, please.

Comment: list  by date in history page

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#list-dividers
but in date not a letter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reformate your JSON like this:

```
public cats: any = [
  { 
    title: "20/03/2017",
    items: [
      { name: "saurabh" },
      { name: "rahul" }
    ]
  },
  { 
    title: "20/04/2017",
    items: [
      { name: "mukesh" }
    ]
  }
];
```

With this you can use following architecture for your page:

```
<ion-item-group *ngFor="let cat of cats">
  <ion-item-divider>{{cat.title}}</ion-item-divider>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of cat.items">{{item.name}}</ion-item>
</ion-item-group>
```

So the only thing, you need to do, is to reformate your JSON.